# camlp5 IFNDEF STRICT doing the opposite of what I expect

Tags: camlp4

HOL Light has some tortured camlp5 logic to change the syntax of ocaml.  I've patched it to work under ocaml 4.04 and 6.17, but it only works under camlp5 [strict mode](http://camlp5.gforge.inria.fr/doc/htmlc/strict.html).  I've traced the problem to [the following code](https://github.com/girving/hol-light/blob/3171fc8931e3bdfc047081b2693c8f3a1b272ea8/pa_j_tweak.ml#L43):

```
value vala_map f =
  IFNDEF STRICT THEN
    fun x -> f x
  ELSE
    fun
    [ Ploc.VaAnt s -> Ploc.VaAnt s
    | Ploc.VaVal x -> Ploc.VaVal (f x) ]
  END
;
```

To the best of my understanding, this should execute the second macro branch if `STRICT` is defined, and the first if `STRICT` is not defined.  I've checked with `camlp5r pa_macro.cmo -defined` that `STRICT` is defined on my machine with camlp5 strict mode, and undefined on my machine with camlp5 transitional mode.

Unfortunately, the second branch is taken on both machines, as if `STRICT` was defined on both.  Changing `IFNDEF STRICT THEN` to `IFNDEF BLAH THEN` switches to the first branch, again as if `STRICT` was defined on both.  However, putting an `UNDEF STRICT;` immediately before the code has no effect.

I'm at a loss, and would love any suggestions for what might be happening, or experiments to run next.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved: one of the modules imported by that file explicitly turns on strict mode.  The `UNDEF` had no effect because `STRICT` is apparently a specially handled builtin.